# How to get sysdate in talend using mongodb connector

Tags: mongodb, date, etl, talend

I have talend and mongodb on two different servers and two different zones ( these timezones may change in future). I am trying to set context variable in taled to mongodb sysdate. I have tried few ways using tMongodbInput and tMongodbRow with new Date(), new ISODate() and $currentDate methods. But it is either a JSON parse exception or Bad Command. I am looking for mongodb query for select sysdate from dual. Is there any way to get sysdate like this in taled using mongodb

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure if you still need this, but you can do your mongodb query like this:

```
{'comparison_date':{$lt:{$date: '" + context.date + "'}}}
```

$lt = less than comparison
$date = date object

having your date either stored in a context variable named 'date' like this: "2019-01-17T00:00:00.000Z" or within the code is up to you; also, i guess the timestamp could be optional

to set the current date you can use a tJava component and set it to the context variable